# Compare every group with every other group in data.table

Tags: r, loops, data.table

I am looking for a `data.table` way to potentially eliminate a double for loop. I am trying to compare every group with every other group with the DTW algorithm.

Here a MWE (not optimized):

```
library(data.table)
library(SimilarityMeasures)

tt <- data.table(A=1:100,B=2:101,C=rep(1:4,each=25))
result <- list()
for(i in 1:4){
  for(j in 1:4){
      result[[4*i+j]] <- DTW(tt[C==i,cbind(A,B)],tt[C==j,cbind(A,B)]) 
  }

}
result
```

A and B are some variables that are used as the input to the DTW algorithm, C is the grouping variable. I tried to come up with some lapply solution combined with a `.SD` or .`BY` approach in `data.table`, but failed. The goal is to have a much faster function than the above double for loop (even when running it in parallel).

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> I am looking for a data.table way to potentially eliminate a double for loop.

This is my suggestion instead of a for loop and number-indexed list:

```
s = lapply(split(tt, by="C", keep=FALSE), as.matrix)
f = sum

res = tt[, CJ(C1 = C, C2 = C, unique=TRUE)]
res[, v := f(s[[C1]], s[[C2]]), by=.(C1, C2)]
```

(I can't install your package and so use some `f` instead of `DTW`. I'm converting to matrix, since I assume that's why you use `cbind`.)

Generally, enumerating combos and using `by=` is a way to avoid / reformulate a loop with data.table.

Precomputing the subsetted matrices `s` might help with performance, but this is still essentially a loop. I doubt there is much further optimization that can be made here.

Comment: Thanks Frank. This is an interesting approach. Unfortunately, it is actually more or less as fast as my original post (even a bit slower). Any other ideas?

Comment: @PukiLuki Ok, good to know. (I don't really have any further ideas, but...) I'd suggest looking up how to use built-in "profiling" tools for R. They can tell you what is taking up most of the time. If it turns out to be DTW(), then I guess there's not much room for improvement if you need to compute all comparisons. If it turns out to be something else, then you can look into simplifying that part of the code.